# Does the investigator have to evade after combat?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

I've been through the rule book several times and we've only played the game twice so it could be I'm missing something. The scenario is this:

The keeper moves a monster into an investigator's space.  The keeper's turn ends after keeper actions and the investigator uses their action to fight the monster.  The investigator wins and the monster takes damage, but does not die.  The investigator then wants to use their 2 moves.

Does the investigator have to roll for evade?  Does the answer to that question make a difference if the investigator won or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you must **Evade** a monster to take any other action than **Attack**, it doesn't matter if you succeeded in your attack. From the [rules (page 9, 14, and 15)](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/MansionsOfMadnessLoRes.pdf).

> Attacking a monster is the only action that an investigator can perform while a monster is in his space (unless he evades the monster, see “Evade Tests” on page 14).
>
> An investigator must make an evade test against every monster in his space before moving or performing non-attack actions. [...] Regardless of whether he passes or fails, the investigator may then move or perform the intended action. After having attempted to evade a monster, the investigator may freely move and take actions without having to try to evade the same monster that turn. [...] Attacking a monster does not require making an evade test. This attack may be unarmed, with a weapon, or with an “attack” Spell card. This attack does not need to target a monster in the investigator’s space.

[Stunned monsters](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/mansions-faq-v-2.pdf) do not need to be evaded.

> Q: Do stunned monsters cause evade checks? What about horror checks? Can they take samples?
>
> A: Investigators can freely evade stunned monsters (because they cannot attack). Stunned monsters still cause Horror checks and can still take samples (although they are not moved after taking the sample).

Comment: Thanks.  I don't disagree with you. I think the instructions could have stated it explicitly, however.  Evade implies (to me) not wanting to interact.  Seeing as how I just kicked its butt, I would think evade wouldn't be necessary. ;)

Comment: @Gregg, the rules do state it explicitly. That was the point of the rules quotes, "Attacking a monster is the **only action** that an investigator can perform while a monster is in his space [...]"